# Custom User Fields for Wordpress - What's the best solution?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, mailchimp, custom-fields

I've been grappling for a few days with this complex problem, and would be most grateful for your opinions!

We are building a music eLearning site where we need to find a way to track each user's progression through a number of 'Learning Objectives'.

Each Learning Objective is expressed in a way that's similar to a Use Case, with a value of TRUE or FALSE.

e.g.

**Data Field:** LEARNER can do X Y and Z.

**Value:** 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' (False is the default)

**

I'm trying to find a way of doing this within [our Wordpress site](http://www.violinschool.org/), where we are using the MEMBERMOUSE plugin to handle subscriptions and billing.

I also need to synchronise data to MAILCHIMP so that users receive the correct communications according to their progress (i.e. as the **value** of the **data fields** changes).

**

I have been searching for Wordpress Plugins that handle 'custom user data fields', and I found these:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-meta/

http://user-meta.com/

Also wondering about [Toolset Types](https://wp-types.com/) which we already have installed - this seems to be able to generate Custom User Fields.

But one of the key issues seems to be that a lot of these existing solutions are set up only for a SMALL NUMBER of custom fields... we need to handle up to 5000 per user! So customisation of back end display is an issue...

I am also assuming that I'll have to commission someone to do some kind of Custom API connection between Mailchimp and Wordpress?

**

Does this sound like a sensible approach? Do you think I'm going about this problem the right way, or would you recommend a different approach?

Am I being naive to try and accomplish this with existing plugins and limited skills (basic wp/html/css only) - should I accept I probably can't do this on my own, and try and commission a custom plugin instead?

Thank you so much for your suggestions! :)

Comment: As you mentioned MailChimp. you can have free plugins out there also. That is not a problem. But as you described... exactly that thing is not available in the market. User meta is a fine plugin. I suggest you get someone to add some extra functionality in your site. And that should not be a huge task for a WordPress developer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Advanced custom fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)